# Does GCE work with distributions other than debian and RHEL?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I see only debian and RHEL images listed... What if I want to run ubuntu 12.04 or something else?  Is there a way to bring up a debian instance and install ubuntu 12.04 on top of it and make my own image?

Answer (score 5):

Since the [General Availability](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/12/google-compute-engine-is-now-generally-available.html) launch, it is possible to use standard kernels with Compute Engine.

Paul Rashidi has posted detailed steps for [creating a FreeBSD image](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-discussion/YWoa3Aa_49U/FYAg9oiRlLUJ). You should be able to create an Ubuntu image from scratch by following similar steps.

If you'd like to modify an existing image, here are detailed steps for [creating a custom image.](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#installinganimage)

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu specifically, [Canonical and Google now provide GCE images for Ubuntu](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/11/curated-ubuntu-images-now-available-on.html).

You can find more information on how to spin up instances using these images in [the GCE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems#ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Google offers images for Debian 7, CentOS 6, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 and SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11. Windows Server 2008 R2 is [coming soon](http://www.neowin.net/news/google-compute-engine-now-supports-windows-server-2008-r2)

You can also [build you own images](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#buildingimage)